# Node.js request charset issues

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, http-headers, request

I'm building a nodejs web crawler but I'm running into some charset issues. Different websites have different charsets, like UTF-8, windows-1252, iso-8859-1 etc.

How can I adapt my request to convert all charsets different than UTF-8 to UTF-8? Because if I don't do anything and simply use cheerio to parse the content, I'm getting weird symbols like "ib�rica" where "�" is suppose to be an "é"

Answer (score 1):

There are [iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) (requires compilation) and [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) (requires no compilation) for converting between character sets in node.